# How do I make a bootable USB flash disk of Windows setup on my Kali Linux system?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, kali-linux

I have Kali Linux currently running on my laptop. I want to install Windows 7. I don't have CD ROM ,how do I make bootable USB having Windows ISO?

Which software will help me?  Or just how to make usb bootable?  I want to install Windows 7 again.

Comment: please somebody answer ..

Answer (score 3):

If you like to use terminal, use the command: `sudo dd if=your_iso_here of=your_drive_here bs=512k`. That will make a live win7 usb.

Answer (score 2):

Use unetbootin in kali linux which helps  you to make a window 7 bootable USB.

Steps to make bootable USB:

1. Open applications button situated in top of the kali screen then go to system tools option after that click on unetbootin option in last.
2. Choose a OS or distribution which you want to make bootable if it is not in option then usually click on disk image option in bottom of dialog box after that browse ISO file from browse option, after selecting then select the USB which you want to make bootable.
3. Use Next or Ok then the USB will become bootable after given time.

Answer (score 1):

You probably already answered this, but look into winusb. it will make a bootable windows disc. It also depends on the bootloader you have installed on your machine. Depending on whether you want dual boot or not, you may be better off making a bootable usb stick from a windows machine, making it on linux can be a pain.

Answer (score 1):

WoeUSB is a tool for creating a bootable USB flash drive used for installing Windows. Native UEFI booting is supported for Windows 7 and later images. WoeUSB is an updated fork of the WinUSB project.

Some third-party installers feature Windows installation images (`/sources/install.wim`) greater than 4GB making FAT32 as target filesystem impossible. NTFS filesystem support has been added to WoeUSB 3.0.0 and later.

#### Installation

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install woeusb
```

This will install the WoeUSB graphical interface and the WoeUSB command line tool. WoeUSB supports both UEFI and BIOS for FAT32/NTFS/ExFAT USB flash drives.

The WoeUSB GUI is easier to use than the WoeUSB command line tool. Click the radio button to the left of where it says *From a disk image (iso)*, browse to the location of the Windows .iso file, under *Target device* select a USB flash drive, open Disks application and check that the Device name in Disks matches the Target device in WoeUSB (it should be something like /dev/sd**X** where **X** is a letter of the alphabet), and click the *Install* button to install to create a bootable Windows installation media on the USB flash drive.

[image]

[WoeUSB Issues](https://askubuntu.com/a/1243565/)